# Need help converting kilograms to pounds and ounces

Tags: java

For some reason this conversion really mess with my head. I can do the conversion on paper and in my head but when I try to write it for my homework in Java it really messes me up. The assignment is for user to enter a number in kilograms and to write a program that says, this is how many pounds on one line and this is how many ounces on another. Conversions in general mess me up but I'm not sure if this is correct. Do I need to use a type cast anywhere?

```
import acm.program.*;

public class KilogramsToPoundsAndOunces extends ConsoleProgram {

public void run(){
println("This programs converts kilograms into pounds and ounces.");
double kilo = readDouble("Enter the kilogram value: "); 
double totalOunces = (kilo * POUNDS_PER_KILOGRAM) * OUNCES_PER_POUND; 
int totalPounds = totalOunces % OUNCES_PER_POUND; 
double leftOverOunces = totalOunces - (totalPounds * OUNCES_PER_POUND);  
println(totalPounds + "lbs" + ".");
println(leftOverOunces + "ozs" + ".")

}
private static void POUNDS_PER_KILOGRAM = 2.2; 
private static void OUNCES_PER_POUND = 16; 
}
```

Comment: you'll get more helpful answers if you say what you're finding difficult. Do you get unexpected output? What is the input and unexpected output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define numeric data types for your constants:

```
private static double POUNDS_PER_KILOGRAM = 2.2; 
private static int OUNCES_PER_POUND = 16;
```

Also `totalPounds` would need to be cast to an `int` to compile:

```
int totalPounds = (int) (totalOunces % OUNCES_PER_POUND);
```

Although this *should* be:

```
int totalPounds = (int) (totalOunces / OUNCES_PER_POUND);
```

(See @Kleanthis answer)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how i forgot to put the type in my constants and for some reason I got % and / reversed in my head.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, the globals `POUNDS_PER_KILOGRAM` and `OUNCES_PER_POUND` are variables, therefore do not have a return type (you have them "returning" void).

Prefer:

```
private final double POUNDS_PER_KILOGRAM = 2.2;
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how i forgot that.

Answer (score 1):

I think where the program goes wrong is at:

```
int totalPounds = totalOunces % OUNCES_PER_POUND;
double leftOverOunces = totalOunces - (totalPounds * OUNCES_PER_POUND);
```

You see the modulo operator does not return the total pounds but the leftover ounces once you get as many complete pounts as possible. Eg

```
int leftoverOunces = totalOunces % OUNCES_PER_POUND;
```

and

```
int totalPounds = (int)(totalOunses/OUNCES_PER_POUND);
```

that should get you the right results.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason i got the % and / reversed in my head.